# How to bind telerik:RadGrid to PlaceHolder in same page using C#?

Tags: c#, telerik

I have One RadGrid. Below is my RadGridview.

```
<div>
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="CommonDataGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
                    <MasterTableView>
                        <Columns>

                           </Columns>
                    </MasterTableView>
                    <ClientSettings>
                        <ClientEvents OnRowContextMenu="RowContextmenufunction"></ClientEvents>
                        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
                    </ClientSettings>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
</div>
<div>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>  
</div>
<div>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>  
</div>
```

Step 1:
I would like to set visbile false to RadGrid.

Step 2:
I would like to show GridView in both `PlaceHolder1 & PlaceHolder2`.

How to do it ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

First **set** `Visible="false"` in **radgrid**

If you want to display the radgrid in both placeholders on page load, then the follow the below code.

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CommonDataGrid.Visible=true;
  PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(CommonDataGrid);
  PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(CommonDataGrid);
}
```